# Weird jsPerf behavior for recursive function

Tags: javascript, jsperf

I have the following code in a test case on jsPerf:

```
var arr = [0, 45, 96, 8, 69, 62, 80, 91, 89, 24, 6, 23, 49, 88, 26, 40, 87, 61, 83, 2, 60, 53, 43, 82, 67, 3, 65, 37, 42, 77, 73, 38, 9, 46, 75, 10, 63, 15, 47, 28, 79, 55, 59, 95, 11, 93, 70, 98, 25, 48, 30, 5, 72, 12, 84, 1, 29, 13, 50, 33, 19, 7, 31, 57, 32, 44, 74, 51, 35, 90, 86, 54, 4, 64, 92, 71, 22, 41, 16, 17, 27, 76, 39, 18, 99, 94, 36, 66, 85, 20, 21, 56, 34, 81, 14, 78, 68, 58, 97, 52];

Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
  var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
  this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
  return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};

function quicksort( arr ) {
  if ( arr.length <= 1 ) 
    return arr;
  var i = 0, 
      len = arr.length, 
      less = [], 
      greater = [], 
      random = Math.floor( Math.random() * len ), 
      pivot = arr[ random ];
  arr.remove( random );
  for ( ; i < len - 1; i++ ){
    if ( arr[ i ] <= pivot )
      less.push( arr[ i ] );
    else 
      greater.push( arr[ i ] );
  }
  return quicksort( less ).concat( pivot, quicksort( greater ) );
};
```

If you copy that into your console and run `quicksort( arr )`, you'll see that it correctly returns a sorted array.

But for some reason, in [this test case](http://jsperf.com/simple-insertion-sort-v-native-sort/2) on jsPerf, my quicksort function seems to be returning only a single number ( as can be seen in 'Perparation Code Output' ). It also seems to be running way faster than it probably should.

Anybody ideas into what's going on would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Firefox I don't see *anything* in the "Preparation code output" ...

Comment: Also if you *really* want to try for a faster sort, you should be doing your quicksort in-place. Creating new sub-arrays is definitely going to kill performance.  The way you'd do that is to pass the from/to indexes into the array down to the recursive levels.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm seeing the no output thing in Firefox too. That's weird.

Also: An in-place quicksort was going to be my next test case before this nonsense happened.

Comment: The reason for no output in Firefox is that it doesn't have an innerText property on HTML nodes, so you're just setting a random property on the node in that one.

Comment: And there you have it kids: don't let yourself come to rely on DOM libraries. Thanks for the heads-up, @TheKaneda. I've edited the test to use innerHTML instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think  the problem is that you're calling that `.remove()` function *on the original array*, so it quickly strips it down to nothing.  In other words, each initial call to the quicksort function removes an element.

[When I make it create a *copy* of the array first](http://jsperf.com/simple-insertion-sort-v-native-sort/5), then it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks, pointy. Just realized the same thing. I called `quicksort( arr.slice( 0 ) )` and everything works now.